# The difference between the method defined using the following two

Tags: javascript

Snippet1:

```
 var box = function() {};

 box.prototype.open = function {
 };
```

Snippet2:

```
  var box = function() {
      this.open = function() {
      };
  }
```

Any difference between those two, which one is better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shall we assume that `box` is a constructor, so you're doing `new box()`?

If so...

- The first version will share the `open` function among all objects created from the `box` constructor.
- The second will generate a new function object for every object created from the `box` constructor.

As such, the first will be more memory efficient than the second.

---

First version:

```
    new box                 box prototype            object prototype
+--------------+          +--------------+          +--------------+
|              |          |              |          |              |
|              |--------->|  open func   |--------->|              |
|              |       /  |              |          |              |
+______________+      /   +______________+          +______________+
                     /
                    /
    new box        /
+--------------+  /
|              | /
|              |/
|              |
+______________+
```

Second version:

```
    new box                box prototype            object prototype
+--------------+          +--------------+          +--------------+
|              |          |              |          |              |
|  open func   |--------->|              |--------->|              |
|              |       /  |              |          |              |
+______________+      /   +______________+          +______________+
                     /
                    /
    new box        /
+--------------+  /
|              | /
|  open func   |/
|              |
+______________+
```

Comment: But (since you didn't say it explicitly) the second is more appropriate _if_ for some reason there is a need to have the function defined individually for each instance - not a very common situation, but still...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes, good point. There certainly are valid occasions to have the function created in the constructor, and assigned directly.

Answer (score 5):

@am not i am is correct. First method is the efficient way to do it. 
Second method is useful if you need private variables.

```
var box = function() {
     var _message = "hello world";
     this.func2 = function(){
       console.log(_message);   // prints hello world
     }
};

box.prototype.func1 = function() {
     this.func2();              // prints hello world
     console.log(_message);     // throws ReferenceError: _message is not defined 
};
```

Comment: +1 for providing valid use case for assigning unique functions to each object.